# Rails3 jquery autocomplete distinct values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

Is it possible to select DISTINCT values using Rails3 JQuery autocomplete gem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is much better and simpler to use scopes.

In your model:

```
scope :uniquely_named, group(:name)
```

In your controller:

```
autocomplete :user, :name, :scopes => [:uniquely_named]
```

This solution allows more complex filtering to be easily applied:

model:

```
scope :uniquely_named, group(:name)
scope :online, where(:online => true)
```

controller:

```
autocomplete :user, :name, :scopes => [:uniquely_named, :online]
```

[source](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/issues/25#issuecomment-1218445)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't appear to - *but* - the 'autocomplete' macro is really just defining an action in your controller. I'd forego using 'autocomplete' in my controller and just implement the action myself...

```
def autocomplete_for_user_name
   User.select('distinct name')
end
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I try this:

```
class UbicationsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :ubication, :name

  def autocomplete_ubication_name
    render json: Ubication.select("DISTINCT name as value").where("LOWER(name) like LOWER(?)", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

None of other answers works with MongoID.

I use a mix of many answers to do this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :product, :manufacturer
  autocomplete :product, :model

  def autocomplete_product_manufacturer
    render_autocomplete(:manufacturer)
  end

  def autocomplete_product_model
    render_autocomplete(:model)
  end

  def render_autocomplete(field)
    render json: Product.where(field => /#{params[:term]}/i).where(domain: @domain).distinct(field)
  end
end
```

This does not use relations. The manufacturer and model are string field on Product model.

Thanks you all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Postgresql:**

```
   scope :uniquely_named, :select => 'distinct name' #In model
   autocomplete :user, :name, :scopes => [:uniquely_named] #In controller
```